# Clear database result set of items with lower SeqNo

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which returns something like this:

```
ID    FieldName    Value        SeqNo
--    ---------    -----        -----
45    {AAA}        Something    1 
12    {BBB}        Something2   2
34    {CCC}        Something3   3 
23    {BBB}        Something4   4
```

I need to clear out all the records which have FieldNames which are already present in the result set but have a higher sequence number. 
So in the above example, my result set should not return ID=12.

**Update:**
I know I can join this query to a copy of itself which groups by FieldName/SeqNo, but it is a pretty intensive query and calling it one more time might be too costly on the optimization side

Comment: Something like group by FieldName having max(SeqNo) then?

Comment: You could always do it programatically; cycle through the full set of results and push the appropriate values into an array, then traverse the array rather than the results.

Comment: i will probably take this path if there is no good solution. since i already have a lot of data scrubbing and filtering in the query already, i was hoping to add this part to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'row_number()' and 'cte'

```
;with cte as (
select id, fieldname, value, seqnum, row_number() over (partition by fieldname order by seqnum desc) rn
from table
)
Select id, fieldname, value, seqnum
From cte
Where rn=1
```

Comment: +1: This is more efficient than the `Exists` method I posted. I usually avoid CTEs in my answer unless they specify the version of SQL, but this is best. The only minor tweak would be to change the "*" to the list of records in case you're pulling in extraneous rows to your resultset that could limit index usage. This should be assumed by the OP though.

Comment: @Love2Learn, I'm on the phone, so * was to minimise typing. Will update though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, FieldName, Value, SeqNo
from tablename
group by FieldName, Value, SeqNo, ID
having max(SeqNo)
```

Comment: When you group you need to include all items in select list into the group clause

Comment: No you don't, that would be lunacy. I tested this before I posted it. It works.

Comment: SQL Server it does not work. Column 'TestTable.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: sql-server wasn't tagged when I posted; sour. It works in mysql.

Comment: i think mysql's syntax works differently from mssql because in that query since you are grouping by ID and all the records have unique ids, it will return all the records. I will try to upvote this back to 0 because i didnt tag my original post as #sql-server (sorry about that).

Comment: This doesn't work, the column they care about duplication on is FieldName, with the grouping you have you would make the ID 12 unique to itself.

Comment: Then how are you supposed to do a simple having join in sql-server? Because apparently you need to include all selected fields in a sql-server query having clause for it to work properly.

Comment: Having works within the context of what SQL Server allows, it does not appear to have the functionality you are describing from mysql. What you have to do is only return the fieldName and SeqNo in a subquery and join that back on SeqNo and FieldName.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  ID, FieldName, Value, SeqNo
From    [tableExample] t
Where   Not Exists (Select  1
                    From    [tableExample] t2
                    Where   t.fieldName = t2.fieldName
                    And     t.SeqNo < t2.SeqNo
```